# How Google Web Font works ?

Tags: css, fonts

I just discovered [Google Web Font](http://www.google.com/webfonts) and I was really interested in how this tool could work...

With just a

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

You can use whatever Google has in his fonts collection.

Do you have any idea on how this stuff works ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply returns CSS that includes [@font-face](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule) rules that allow you to use fonts that are accessible over the web versus on the client's local machine. Note that not all browsers [support](http://caniuse.com/fontface) `@font-face`.

Comment: But where is the "if IE7" part ? 

It's amazing that even IE7 works with this !

Answer (score 0):

Choose a font here

http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace:select

and select Quick use

When you're on the font page, scroll down a little and you'll have 3 choice to add this font in standard mode, @import or javascript.

This stuff is simply working by loading the @face-font from Google's server without you have to install them on yours. This could result to a faster loading but more you and custom web font, more time it will take to load. So choose wisely.